# Can't create flash drive for Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04

I have downloaded `kubuntu-17.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

So on my terminal:

```
lsblk
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dd if=kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sda bs=4096
```

But it does not work. I use the same lines above to create flash drive for Kubuntu 16.10 and no problem at all.

Why?

Is `kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso` that I downloaded corrupted?

Comment: @duncan sorry it is `kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso` i updated my query.

Comment: What do you mean that it does not works? do you get an error? is `dd` works but your drive doesn't ?

Comment: @Ravexina no error.  nothing happens when insert it for installation.

Comment: @teelou what is the output of `sha256sum kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso`? it should be `e702ac36901679c71d42ebf0aab9e5dff520121a7cb1eac02c91e2db53df7e9d`; if it's not then your iso is corrupted.